# Which of the taxonomy categories could fit the example provided by this post?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice

We know that 'scientific disciplines divide the particulars they study into kinds'. But there are also taxonomy categories that rank above a kind (of particulars). In that case, the kind mediates that higher category and a particular: it acts as a middle category between them. For example, a biological species mediate a relevant particular and a genus, a member of which the species is itself. In this case, the name for the middle category is a species and for the higher one genus.

Now consider an example I am specifically interested in. Each object is characterised by the property of color (a higher category here); furthermore, we do not have one color but instead many kinds of color (white, yellow etc.--a middle category) which are instantiated by objects in the form of actual particular instances of them (a particular).

What would be right words (names) for the middle and higher categories in this example (for I doubt that the 'species' and the 'genus' could fit there)?

Comment: Color ***family*** certainly seems to make sense.

Comment: Or group.  Look up "color"--there are many words having to do with color--hue, tint, etc. that relate to different aspects of color.

Comment: Do you mean 'family' as the higher category (the property of color) and a kind as the middle one (white etc.)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

“In the process of classification one begins with a group of individuals (leafs) and arranges them into classes (twigs), called infimae*) species, none of which can be broken down into species but only into individuals.” (Without leafs and twigs, cited From Encyclopedia of Philosophy, ed. Borchert, 2006, Logical Terms, Glossary of, “Classification”, p. 537, Vol. ?)

I have the impression that you want a natural and not an abstract classification. In this case the picture of a living tree would perhaps be appropriate. The categories are
**leaf** (individual) …. **twig** (e.g. cyan) …. **branch** (property “Color”) … and **trunk** (property in a wider sense).

This classification may be further extended to the roots and to other trees of the forest and even to the air.

class of all properties................summum genus.........................**trunk**……….....highest class

the property "color"..................proximum genus........................**branch**………..a middle class

a color, e.g. cyan.......................kind (infima species)…………......**twig**…………....the lowest class

---..............................................individuals……………………….......**leaf**……………..---

---

*)  lat. infima = lowest (infimae = plural)

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re proposing here.

Comment: @Jim: Why not? -- I only listed the (officially) appropriate names (incidentally, I collected them some years ago) for the “middle class” and the “highest class” that exist in the English language -- As for me, I am not satisfied with this scratch-terminology. In German there exists some continuity: **Oberbegriff** -- **Begriff** -- **Begriffs**umfang. ... But in English the vocabulary is very poor in this respect. What I did, was just a demonstration of this gap.

Comment: So you’re proposing what exactly to be analogous to “family-genus- species”?  “general term - class - subsumption” (the bolded terms) or “highest class  -  middle class  -  kind”?  None of those make sense to me.

Comment: Please can you take the time to explain your answer in full. As it is, it is very confusing to look at.

Comment: @Jim: A subsumption is a class (e.g. the property “color”) with subsumed elements (the kinds of colors). However, these subsumed elements are themselves subsumptions again, because there are, for instance, different kinds of yellows (as elements). -- However, “subsumption” means also “narrower term” (i.e. member of a class). That’s why I was so “bold” to oppose it to “class” (although logically it is also a class). “Property” is of course analogous to “family”. And genus encompasses all the properties. – But, biological systematics is anyway not really analogous to physical appearances.

Comment: @Jim Perhaps the topic deserves a discussion here; I mean in case Zeus  is correct concerning "in English the vocabulary is very poor in this respect" (a claim I am not competent in the validity of) it would not be bad to add some clarity to the topic for future uses here as well. Bearing in mind Zeus' term of 'continuity', I would reformulate the topic this way--what is taxonomy terminology  for the middle category that is the closest or nearest (general) category to both a higher one and the particulars it directly includes.

Comment: Sorry for an error; the question must be read: what is taxonomy terminology for a higher and a middle category where the middle one is the closest (general) category to both the higher one and the particulars it includes.

Comment: I think that now I have found the solution, and I have radically changed my answer in a new edit.